# Why is umask ignored when uploading files over sftp?

Tags: sftp, umask

Have a wierd issue with permissions on files uploaded to a remote system.

Locally, the file index2.html is chmod 664:

```
acoder@acoder-local ~ $ ll index2.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 acoder acoder    29 May 17 14:46 index2.html
```

After uploading this same file to the remote system, the permissions on the remote directory show:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 acoder acoder 3657 May 17 14:43 index2.html
```

I first thought I had incorrect umask setting on the remote system, but...

```
[acoder@remote public_html]$ umask
0002
```

For comparison, if I touch a file on the remote system, the correct permissions (for the given umask) show:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 acoder acoder    0 May 17 14:44 index3.html
```

So, how are permissions set on files uploaded via sftp?  Why is umask ignored when placing files over sftp?

Comment: What umask are you specifying with the `-u` option of the server? Does it support `-u`?

Comment: I don't follow. Are you saying I should pass a separate umask with the sftp options?

Comment: Where is your `umask` set? In the shell startup files? I can't remember if `sftp` is started through the shell on the server, but even if it is, it's a non-interactive shell, and your shell probably doesn't read the usual startup files in that case. So any changes to `umask` there won't be visible to the `sftp` server

Comment: @ilkkachu SFTP does not go through the login shell at all (unlike anything else using SSH).

Answer (score 3):

SFTP does not go through a login shell at all. It's directly managed by the SSH server. If the umask you expect is set by `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or some other shell initialization file then it doesn't apply to SFTP.

You can set an umask through the [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) module [`pam_umask`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_umask.html). The setting for the SSH server will apply to both SSH shell sessions (unless overridden by a shell initialization file) and SFTP sessions.

You can also set the umask for SSH specifically by editing the `Subsystem sftp` line of `/etc/sshd_config` to pass the `-u` option to [`sftp-server`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sftp-server.8.html).

Comment: I tried changing `/etc/login.defs` UMASK value to 002, but no luck - same permissions as before (detailed in question).

Comment: Also tried editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with Subsystem sftp internal-sftp **-u 0022**, restarted sshd service, still same permissions issue.

Comment: @acoder did you resolve this finally?

Answer (score 0):

To do this through PAM, as suggested by Gilles, all that should be necessary is adding the desired umask to the user's entry in `/etc/passwd` like so:

```
usermod -c ,,,,umask=002 acoder
```

Although this method replaces the whole GECOS field. So any potential existing information should be included in the above command as well.

This should work if the `pam_umask` module is used. Which it appears to be by default on Fedora and CentOS Stream 9 (`/etc/pam.d/postlogin`).